# jquery, how to enable this checkbox that has unique type, name and value

Tags: jquery

I created this somewhere in perl:

```
print qq|<td><input type="checkbox" name="dbtableselect" value="$row[0]"/></td>|;
```

I tried this syntax but it isn't working. what is the correct syntax format?

```
 var keyid = \$(this).attr('name').match(/\d+/g);

 \$('input[type=checkbox,name=dbtableselect,value=' + keyid + ').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [Attribute Equals Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). Each attribute comparison goes into it's own pair of square brackets, like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=dbtableselect][value=' + keyid + ']').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$('input[type=checkbox][name=dbtableselect][value=' + keyid + ']')`.